# DJANGO, update button is not working in frontend but in admin panel, i can change the status

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

When i click the update button, it should change the remarks/status of the submitted file in submission, however i dont know why it is working in my frontend but it works in my django admin panel. Please help me huhu, and also i dont want to use AJAX cause it's so complicated to use

html

```
{% extends "base/room_home.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>{{ room_bills.title }}</h1>
        <p>Due: {{ room_bills.due }}</p>

        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Paid Members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for submission in submissions %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="proof/{{ submission.user.id }}" target="_blank">{{ submission.user.username }}</a>
                        {% if submission %}
                            <form method="POST" class="update-form" data-room-id="{{ room_bills.room.id }}" data-bills-slug="{{ room_bills.slug }}" data-submission-id="{{ submission.id }}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <select name="status">
                                    <option value="P" {% if submission.status == 'P' %}selected{% endif %}>Pending</option>
                                    <option value="A" {% if submission.status == 'A' %}selected{% endif %}>Accepted</option>
                                    <option value="R" {% if submission.status == 'R' %}selected{% endif %}>Rejected</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                            </form>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <h3>Did not pay members: </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for user in did_not_submit %}
                    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('.update-form').forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const data = {
                room_id: form.dataset.roomId,
                bills_slug: form.dataset.billsSlug,
                submission_id: form.dataset.submissionId,
                status: form.elements['status'].value,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
            };

            fetch(`/room/${data.room_id}/bills/${data.bills_slug}/status/`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                 if (data.success) {
                      console.log("Status updated successfully");
                 } else {
                      console.error("Failed to update status");
                 }
              })
              .catch(error => {
                 console.error("Error:", error);
              });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def remark_proof_api(request, room_id, bills_slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))

        submission_id = data["subId"]
        status = data["status"]

        sub = Submission.objects.get(id=int(submission_id))
        sub.status = status
        sub.save()

        return JsonResponse({"success": True})
```

i tried to debug multiple times but it just wont work

Comment: Please remove the "noise" from the title. Can you share what you see in the console when you make an update? What error do you get?

Comment: hiii,, it says "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" (console error part)

and
invalid in fetch part

Comment: can you share the full error message?